# Missing Password decryption code in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net

We have an application we are having an issue we have a method which encrypt the password, but we need another function which decrypt the password.

```
public string Encrypt(string originalPassword)
{
    if (originalPassword == null)
        return String.Empty;

    SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    Byte[] originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(originalPassword);
    Byte[] encodedBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

    //Convert encoded bytes back to a 'readable' string
    return BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: Passwords should be salted and hashed, not encrypted

Comment: Passwords should be hashed. They must not be decrypted. Why you want to decrypt the password?

Comment: Agree with @WelcomeOverflow also you may want to take a look at net core identity password hasher implementation here: [https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/src/Core/PasswordHasher.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/src/Core/PasswordHasher.cs)

Comment: SHA is **not** an encryption so it can not be decrypted. It is a hashing algorithm so the only mechanism to obtain the data is brute forcing it.

Comment: You approach on the `decrypt` is wrong. You should Hash the password when saving it and then Hash the password when the user enters it. If the entered Hash matches the saved Hash, then your'e good.

Comment: @Jimenemex the problem with hashing passwords without a salt is that the same password will generate the same hash which is easier to crack using `brute force` or `rainbow tables`

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 6):

Your method is not *encrypting* the password, it's **[hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)** it. You won't be able to recover the original string from the hash - and that's entirely on purpose and by design:

> A cryptographic hash function allows one to easily verify that some
>   input data maps to a given hash value, but if the input data is
>   unknown, it is deliberately difficult to reconstruct it (or any
>   equivalent alternatives) by knowing the stored hash value.

Comment: I'd add that using `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` is basically as insecure as encrypting it

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is a very basic example of how to Hash using PBKDF2 with SHA512:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Security.Cryptography;

...

public string HashPassword(string pswd, string saltValue, long iterations)
{
    byte[] pswdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pswd);
    byte[] saltByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltValue);
    byte[] hashedPassword = null;
    hashedPassword = BCryptPBKDF2.ComputeHash(PBKDF2HashAlgorithm.SHA512, pswdBytes, saltByte, iterations);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedPassword);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public void SaveNewUser(string username, string password)
{
    string salt = GetSalt();
    string hashedPassword = HashPassword(password, salt, 10000);

    // Go save the username, hashed password and salt in the DB
    SaveUserInDatabase(username, hashedPassword, salt);
}

public bool AuthenticateLogin(string username, string password)
{
     // Get the salt saved from the DB for the user somehow
     string salt = GetSaltFromDB(string username);
     string hashedPassword = HashPassword(password, salt, 10000);

     // Get the saved Password from database somehow
     string savedPassword = GetSavedPasswordFromDB(string username);

     if(hashedPassword.Equals(savedPassword))
     {
          return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

When a new user is created, or how ever you initially save the password, `SaveNewUser` is called to Salt, Hash and then save the password and the salt used.

Then when a user logs in, the entered password is again Salted (using the salt saved) and Hashed in `AuthenticateUser`, but this time compared to the saved password. (Of course you need a way to get the same user from the database, but the concept remains the same.)

If the hashes match then the password match the user has entered in the correct password.

Read up on how to create a Salt value [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).